# raspberry pi 4BでAdafruit Python PCA9685をインストールしたい

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

#### 今できていること

raspberry pi 4B（python3.7)でAdafruit Python PCA9685をインストールするため、以下のコマンドでダウンロードしました。

```
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685.git
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO.git
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_PureIO.git
```

ラズパイにインストールするため

```
cd Adafruit_Python_PCA9685
sudo python3 setup.py install
cd ../Adafruit_Python_GPIO
sudo python3 setup.py install
cd ../Adafruit_Python_PureIO
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

を入力しますが、最後の `sudo python3 setup.py install` でエラーが出ます。

```
python3: can't open file '/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_PureIO/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

#### 知りたいこと

setup.pyというファイルがないということですが、どのようにすればAdafruit_Python_PureIOがインストールできるか詳しいやり方など教えていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: `Adafruit_Python_PCA9685`は**DEPRECATED**, `Adafruit_Python_GPIO`も**Deprecation Warning**と記されてますがなぜこれを使おうとしてるのでしょう？
理由があるなら(質問内に)記したほうがよいでしょう。また 3つめの`Adafruit_Python_PureIO`はインストール方法は pip3 使うようです。

Comment: README には `pip3 install Adafruit-PureIO` でインストールする手順が記載されています。

Comment: pip3 install Adafruit-PureIO でインストールを試みましたができませんでした。

Comment: This environment is externally managed
╰─>というメッセージがでます

Comment: `Adafruit_Python_PCA9685` は非推奨だけど, (コメントの反応がないので) 特に理由なく使用している, と判断していいのでしょうか？ 回答付けるとするなら最新版利用することになるけど

Comment: Adafruit_Python_PCA9685を使う理由はラジコンカーに超音波センサーを3個取り付け、車がぶつからないように走行できるようにするために必要なソフトのようです。Adafruit_Python_PCA9685に走行用モーターを制御するようにしています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Adafruit_Python_PCA9685` は "!! DEPRECATED !!"(非推奨) とあり, ほぼ 8年前に更新が止まっています

> このライブラリは非推奨であり、アーカイブされています。こちらの新しいライブラリを使用してください
> https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685

その `Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685` は, 以下のように記されています
参考: [Adafruit PCA9685 Library 1.0 documentation](https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/pca9685/en/latest/)

- Dependencies (依存関係)

  - Adafruit CircuitPython
  - Bus Device
  - Register
- インストール方法

  > On supported GNU/Linux systems like the Raspberry Pi

  - `pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685`
  - 現在のプロジェクトの仮想環境にインストールするには

    ```bash
    mkdir project-name && cd project-name
    python3 -m venv .venv
    source .venv/bin/activate
    pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685
    ```

`project-name` の名前は環境に合わせて適当に決めるとよいでしょう (radicon でも何でも)
CircuitPython については後述

手元の環境では `pipenv`なので以下のように
(この環境では `RPi.GPIO`が不足していたためそれもインストール)

```bash
$ cd pca9685
$ pipenv install adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685
$ pipenv install RPi.GPIO
```

インストールパッケージの一覧

```bash
$ pipenv run pip list
Package                                  Version
---------------------------------------- -------
Adafruit-Blinka                          8.37.0
adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice         5.2.6
adafruit-circuitpython-connectionmanager 1.0.1
adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685           3.4.15
adafruit-circuitpython-register          1.9.18
adafruit-circuitpython-requests          3.2.2
adafruit-circuitpython-typing            1.10.3
Adafruit-PlatformDetect                  3.62.0
Adafruit-PureIO                          1.1.11
pip                                      24.0
pyftdi                                   0.55.0
pyserial                                 3.5
pyusb                                    1.2.1
RPi.GPIO                                 0.7.1
setuptools                               69.1.1
typing_extensions                        4.10.0
wheel                                    0.42.0
```

ドキュメントには, "Usage Example"として `examples/pca9685_simpletest.py` があるので, 正しくインストールできたか確認するとよいでしょう
(pipenv での実行の例。`import` は可能だが環境整っていない為途中まで)

```py
$ pipenv run python
>>> import board
>>> from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685
>>> i2c = board.I2C()
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

---

#### venv, pipenv, conda など仮想環境について

参考: (docs.python.org) [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)

[Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/), Debian, Ubuntu その他, 主に *NIX系では OS側で Pythonが利用されていることも多く, 無闇にパッケージをインストールするとシステムが不安定になる
このため一般的には仮想環境を利用します

(詳細は省略)

venvにしても, pipenvにしても, 未インストール(環境整えていない)なら 何らかのインストールは必要。
venv を利用するには, Raspberry Pi OS, Ubuntu など Debian系では以下のようなパッケージを使うとよいでしょう
(Ubuntuの場合)

```bash
$ apt list *venv*
python3-venv/mantic 3.11.4-5 arm64
python3.11-venv/mantic 3.11.6-3 arm64
python3.12-venv/mantic 3.12.0-1 arm64
```

「`pip3 install Adafruit-PureIO` でエラーの発生」は, 仮想環境を使っていないためと思われます

また, 質問内ではすでに `sudo`指定し setup行ったということなので問題が出るかもしれず,
インストールした場所が特定できるなら削除したほうがよいかもしれない
(もしくは OSごと再インストール)

---

#### CircuitPython

[CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org/) は microcontroller boards 用の Python (もしくは OS的なもの)で Raspberry Pi 4 などの CPython とは多少異なります
主に Raspberry Pi Pico などのマイコンで利用され, `Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685` などから利用できる APIを備えています

上記の「Dependencies (依存関係)」とは, CircuitPython 上でドライバーを利用する場合の話で
CPythonでドライバーを利用するには (それとは別の), [Blinka](https://circuitpython.org/blinka) などの互換部分が必要
(ただし, 上記の pipenv利用の操作ではすでに自動的に入ってるので, 追加する必要はない)

例えば GPIOなどもそうで, OS側のパッケージを利用する必要があるかもしれない

参考: (learn.adafruit.com) [CircuitPython Libraries on Linux and Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux)

- [Installing Blinka on Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/installing-circuitpython-on-raspberry-pi) にその辺りの記述あり

質問からは, ドキュメントよく読まずに操作していることが伺えます
まずこの辺りのドキュメントに一度目を通すことをおすすめします

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございます　インストールがうまくできました　最初は上手くいかなかったので、OSを再インストールして、Adafruitのインストールができました　　わかりやすい回答ありがとうございました　助かりました

Comment: 解決できたようなら [回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) お願いします